# Is there a glitch with opendir/readdir?

Tags: php, active-directory

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

// Enumerate the directories in styles
$styles_dir = 'styles/';

if($handle = opendir($styles_dir))
{
    while(FALSE !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        echo $file . '(' . is_dir($file) . ')<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Here are the directories in `styles`:

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/php.jpg

And here is the output:

```
.(1)
..(1)
forest()
industrial()
```

Why aren't `forest` and `industrial` directories?

Comment: Could it be a permissions problem? Can the script chdir to either of those?

Comment: I don't know. I'll check. It should be able to...

Comment: Yup. It can successfully `chdir` to the `forest` and `industrial` directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for `is_dir` is relative to the base file, so you really need to do a test like

```
is_dir($styles_dir . '/' . $file)
```

Note that this is masked for the `.` and `..` "directories" as these exist everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix the directory name to the file name as `is_dir` works relative to the current directory.

Change

```
echo $file . '(' . is_dir($file) . ')<br>';
```

to

```
echo $file . '(' . is_dir("$styles_dir/$file") . ')<br>';
```

Alternatively you can change the directory to `$styles_dir` using [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) and then your current code will work.